# Running thread simultaneously with program in C

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I would like to run my thread simultaneously as my main program. How do I do so? Currently the thread is running a never ending loop, but i would like it to run at the same time as when my main program continues running. Here is my code.

This is my thread:

```
void *LEDReadingsTimer(char *buffer, int clientSocket) //void *arg
{
    while(timer!=0)
    {
        delay(2000);
        LEDReadings(buffer, clientSocket);
        printf("Data Sent to Android!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here is my main code:

```
timer=1;
  wiringPiSetupSys () ;
  gertboardAnalogSetup (100) ;
  pthread_create(&tid, NULL, LEDReadingsTimer(buffer,clientSocket), NULL);


  //Receive and send data from and to Android
  while(1){ 
      nread = recv(clientSocket,buffer,4096,0);//recvfrom(clientSocket, buffer,1024, 0, (struct sockaddr *) &serverStorage, &addr_size);
      buffer[nread] = '\0';

      if((atof(buffer)>=0)&&(atof(buffer)<=1)){
      printf("Data Received: %s\n", buffer);  
      LEDBrightness(buffer);             
      //LEDReadings(buffer, clientSocket);

  }
```

This is my LEDReadings function.

```
int LEDReadings(char *buffer, int clientSocket){
    int x1, x2 ;
    double v1, v2 ;
    double a;

    printf ("| Channel 0 | Channel 1 |\n") ;
        // Read the 2 channels:
        x1 = analogRead (100) ; //voltage
        x2 = analogRead (101) ; //current
        // Convert to a voltage:
        v1 = (double)x1 / 1023.0 * 3.3 ;
        v2 = (double)x2 / 1023.0 * 3.3 ;
        a = v2*30;
        printf ("%6.3f|%6.3f\n", v1, a) ;
        fflush (stdout) ;
        snprintf(buffer, 4096,"%6.3fsplit%6.3f\n", v1, a);
        send(clientSocket,buffer,strlen(buffer)+1,0);
        return 0;
}
```

Once my pthread runs, it doesn't go into the next while loop to do recv function.

Comment: It's a classic:)   You are not starting any thread because the CALL 'LEDReadingsTimer(buffer,clientSocket)' never returns with any parameter for the pthread_create.

Comment: You MUST have 'pthread_create(&tid, NULL, LEDReadingsTimer, NULL);', the thread function 'LEDReadingsTimer' MUST have the correct signature as described in the docs for pthread_create, and any parameters to be used by the thread function on startup should be provided by the void* last argument to pthread_create.

Comment: `pthread_create` takes a pointer to your start function. Instead you're giving it the return value of some function.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I'm trying to keep sending out data to my android phone every few seconds, while waiting for my android to send in data. So the LEDReadingsTimer must be a void type? However in my case, I require the buffer and clientSocket as inputs from inorder to run the LEDReadings function. Arghhh sorry if i am confusing you

Comment: @pvg I want my function to keep running every few seconds throughout the entire program

Comment: Yeah I get that, you're just not giving `pthread_create` what it expects. I think the answers people are feverishly typing will sort you out. For things like that, it's also helpful to google up some sample code so you can see how it differs from your own.

Comment: @Learning2code no, you are not confusing me, and I understand that the thread function needs those buffer/socket parameters to do its work.  What I am saying is that you cannot pass those arguments in a call to the thread function.  The usual method is to define a struct type that holds all the arguments, malloc an instance, load up that instance with the argument values and then pass the struct instance pointer as the last arguent to pthread_create, (where you have NULL).  The thread function then gets a void* that you can cast back to a struct pointer and retrieve the parameters:)

Comment: Oh - and if your thread functon exits/terminates, don't forget to free() the struct pointer in the thread function before the exit to prevent a leak. If it runs for the entire app lifetime, just don't bother freeing:).

Comment: Thank you pvg and ThingyWotsit, I know how it works now! I'm always happy to learn on this site thanks to very helpful people like you guys! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you know you have to pass `pthread_create()` a function pointer. There's no such thing in C as a "function pointer with arguments", it's just the address of the function. So what you *do* here is just **call a function the normal way**, this function never returns, so the `pthread_create()` is never executed, waiting for evaluation of one of its arguments.

Have a look at the prototype of `pthread_create()`:

```
   int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                      void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

This means your `start_routine` must accept and return `void *`. So you have to change the signature of your function to

```
void *LEDReadingsTimer(void *args);
```

Now, how do you pass the parameters? Simply use a struct. Define this struct somewhere:

```
struct LEDReadingsTimerArgs
{
    char *buffer;
    int clientSocket;
};
```

Then you can change your thread function to this:

```
void *LEDReadingsTimer(void *args)
{
    struct LEDReadingsTimerArgs *lrtArgs = args;
    while(timer!=0)
    {
        delay(2000);
        LEDReadings(lrtArgs->buffer, lrtArgs->clientSocket);
        printf("Data Sent to Android!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The last argument of `pthread_create` is for passing the arguments, so start your thread like this:

```
struct LEDReadingsTimerArgs lrtArgs = {buffer, clientSocket};
pthread_create(&tid, NULL, LEDReadingsTimer, &lrtArgs);
```

Comment: wow! It worked really well for me, thank you so much! I understand it now. Previously i thought you can just run a simple function, I didnt know pthread has to take in a void. And also, I have never used struct before, i will read up more of its uses. Thanks !!!

Comment: A "struct" is just a "complex datatype", consisting of multiple fields of other datatypes. So here you just have a single pointer argument, that's easily solved with a struct.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling the thread function yourself rather than giving it to `pthread_create` as a pointer. This means the function will run forever and no thread will ever be created.

You need to create a way to pass parameters, for example a struct

```
struct params
{
    char *buffer;
    int clientSocket;
}
```

Then you change your thread function into one that gets it as a parameter

```
void *LEDReadingsTimer(void *args)
{
    struct params *pars = args;

    while(timer!=0)
    {
        delay(2000);
        LEDReadings(pars->buffer, pars->clientSocket);
        printf("Data Sent to Android!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And in your main function you define a struct, set values and pass it to the thread funtion through `pthread_create`;

```
struct params pars;
pars.buffer = buffer;
pars.clientSocket = clientSocket;

pthread_create(&tid, NULL, LEDReadingsTimer, &pars);
```

This way your thread function is called by `pthread` and the parameters you pass to it will be usable from the thread. Of course always make sure the parameter struct doesn't go out of scope and get freed while the thread is running.

Comment: Thank you, I understand it now! :)

Comment: Just one nitpick: don't cast `void *` in C.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Stuck in bad habits, thanks for the kick :)